# Detect drag and drop links when closing as duplicate

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

When I close as duplicate, I want to be able to drag a link from a different place (The comments, the Related Questions section, another page), directly into the close as duplicate dialog. Currently, the result is that the placeholder remains (until I click elsewhere), the link is pasted inside the textbox, however, the question isn't loaded.

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]

In order to fix it, I need to, while focused on the text input, hit any button.

My (educated) guess is that it works based on a `keydown` event. Can we please change it to `input` event, like the post editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the next build, dragging content into most "update on change" text fields will trigger an update.